# Erro em concatenação console.log

Tags: javascript

```
var A, B, C;
  A=prompt("Digite um valor.");
  B=prompt("Digite um valor.");
  C=prompt("Digite um valor.");
console.log("TRIANGULO: "+(A*C)/2);
console.log("CIRCULO: "+(3.14159*C*C));
console.log("TRAPEZIO: "+(A+B)*C/2);
console.log("QUADRADO: "+(B*B));
console.log("RETANGULO: "+(A*B));
```

Em `console.log("TRAPEZIO: "+(A+B)*C/2);` o resultado é `34` e não entendi o porque.

Comment: Prompt retorna string, então A+B concatena ao invés de somarem. Use `Number(A) + Number(B)` para resolver.

Comment: Obrigado, eu tentei usar promptNumber mas não consegui. Já havia enfrentado esse problema antes.

Comment: Não existe `promptNumber` ... faça assim: `A=Number(prompt("Digite um valor."));` e depois no console.log isole a operação matematica da string com parenteses: `console.log("TRAPEZIO: " + ((A+B)*C/2) );`